# как указать порядок срабатывания классов

Tags: python, selenium

у меня есть два класса, и при запуске кода срабатывает сначала второй класс а потом первый. Как мне упорядочить из работу (сначала первый потом второй)?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager import driver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pyautogui

class SBMS_start():
    def open_service(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver.get("ссылка сайта")
        self.driver.maximize_window()

        time.sleep(1)
    
    def auth(self):
        driver = self.driver
        time.sleep(1)
        username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("user")
        username_textbox.send_keys("логин")
        time.sleep(1)
        password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
        password.send_keys("пароль")
        time.sleep(1)
        button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div[5]/button')
        button1.click() #ENTER

    def registration_client(self):
        driver = self.driver
        time.sleep(1)
        registartion = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SHELL_MENU.ITEM0040"]/a')
        registartion.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        add_abon = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu-CLIR.ITEM0020"]')
        add_abon.click()

class move_mouse_for_search():
    pyautogui.moveTo(331, 296,duration=0.5)
    pyautogui.click(331,296,duration=0.5)
    pyautogui.write("777772194")

checkbox = SBMS_start()
checkbox.open_service()
checkbox.auth()
checkbox.registration_client()
move = move_mouse_for_search()
```

логика работает кроме проблемы проблемы с порядком классов. Где мой косяк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что вы функции `pyautogui` положили в классовую область видимости. Эти три строки выполняются даже если вы не будете создавать экземпляр класса. Решение простое - использовать их (эти 3 строки) в методе инициализации (`__init__`)

```
class move_mouse_for_search:
    def __init__(self):
        pyautogui.moveTo(331, 296,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.click(331,296,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.write("777772194")

checkbox = SBMS_start()
checkbox.open_service()
checkbox.auth()
checkbox.registration_client()
move_mouse_for_search()
```

А вообще не понятно для чего вам тут целый класс, если можно просто функцию создать и вызвать.

```
def move_mouse_for_search():
    pyautogui.moveTo(331, 296,duration=0.5)
    pyautogui.click(331,296,duration=0.5)
    pyautogui.write("777772194")

checkbox = SBMS_start()
checkbox.open_service()
checkbox.auth()
checkbox.registration_client()
move_mouse_for_search()
```

Comment: действительно. Проблему решил, но сейчас попробую без классов сделать всё

Answer (score 1):

Сначала вызвать второй клас потом первый:

```
move = move_mouse_for_search()
checkbox = SBMS_start()
checkbox.open_service()
checkbox.auth()
checkbox.registration_client()
```

но предполагаю, это вызовет ошибку, так как второй класс исспользует элементы созданные первым, следовательно, перемещаем строку `move=...` на одну ниже, или на две, или на три

Comment: попробовал ваш совет. С первым пунктом согласен и ожидания оправдались. Следующие пункты изменений никаких не дало

Answer (score 0):

и так пошаманил с бубном. В втором классе метод обернул функцией

```
class move_mouse_for_search:
    def move_mouse():
        pyautogui.moveTo(331, 296,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.click(331,296,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.write("777772194")
```

а в конце когда начал вызвать классы и их функции поставил таймер между 1 и 2 классами и их функциями

```
checkbox = SBMS_start()
checkbox.open_service()
checkbox.auth()

time.sleep(2) # таймер для ожидания

ms_move = mouse()
mouse.move_mouse()
```

это мой вариант решения проблемы! Но выше я отметил в качестве правильного вариант коллеги по цеху потому что тот вариант более удобен и прост